# Building Go Application using confluent-kafka-go on Linux

Tags: docker, go, apache-kafka

I am trying to create a docker image with my go application. The application (which was developed on MacOS) depends on `confluent-kafka-go` which in turn depends on `librdkafka-dev` which I install in the Docker image like so:

```
FROM golang:1.1
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install librdkafka-dev

VOLUME /workspace
WORKDIR /workspace/src/my/app/folder
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
```

I am getting the following error:

my/app/folder/vendor/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka
../folder/vendor/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka/00version.go:44:2: error: #error "confluent-kafka-go requires librdkafka v0.11.5 or later. Install the latest version of librdkafka from the Confluent repositories, see http://docs.confluent.io/current/installation.html"

As far as I understand the latest version **is** installed.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a similar issue a few weeks ago. IIRC `confluent-kafka-go` requires a recent version of `librdkafka-dev`, which simply was not yet released to alpine or others. 
I was able to find it for ubuntu though, so my solution (which was more involved than I hoped for, but it worked), was to start from clean ubuntu, install `librdkafka-dev`, install Go version that I want and compile inside docker.

Here's how it looks:

```
FROM ubuntu

# Install the C lib for kafka
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils wget gnupg software-properties-common
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates
RUN wget -qO - https://packages.confluent.io/deb/5.1/archive.key | apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.confluent.io/deb/5.1 stable main"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y librdkafka-dev

# Install Go
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:longsleep/golang-backports
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y golang-1.11-go

# build the library
WORKDIR /go/src/gitlab.appsflyer.com/rantav/kafka-mirror-tester
COPY *.go ./
COPY // the rest of your go files. You may copy recursive if you want
COPY vendor vendor

RUN GOPATH=/go GOOS=linux /usr/lib/go-1.11/bin/go build -a -o main .

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["./main"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a version of package to be installed in apt-get command.
e.g

```
apt-get install librdkafka-dev=0.11.6~1confluent5.0.1-1
```

If that doesn't work then I think the apt sources doesn't have version 0.11.5 of librdkafka.
You can add a repository with the right version of librdkafka in `/etc/apt/sources.list` as described here:
https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html#systemd-ubuntu-debian-install

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a shot